# Field Service Lightning - Update record offline

Tags: servicecloud, field-service-lightning, fieldservice

We are working on FSL Salesforce, we need help in below scenario
Field agent uses FSL app on mobile and update the status of Service appointment according to their work. Suppose today he updated the Service appointment status at 12 PM to complete but internet connection is disconnected and he got connection back at 1 pm then that update time populates 1 PM which is incorrect because client pays them on hourly basis.
Does anyone have the same issue or any idea how we can do this will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add a work completed dt  (date and time field)  that is manully set via quick action and predefine to now() . Have workers save their updates then click save in the quick action. The system will be updated with the the date and time the quick action was saved.